# Solving a simple recurrence

Tags: reference-request, proof-techniques, recurrence-relation

I'm having a real hard time solving recurrences using the substitution method.

Show that: $T(n) = T(n/2) + 1$ is $O(\lg n)$

I thought this to be relatively easy:

We have to show that $T(n) \leq c \lg n$

Substitution gives me:

$\qquad
  \begin{align}
    T(n) &\leq c \lg(n/2) + 1 \\
         &= c \lg n - c \lg 2 + 1 \\
         &= c \lg n - c + 1 \\
         &\leq  c \lg n
\end{align}$

for every c.

I was under the impression this was it, but when I was looking for an answer, I came around a [much more elaborate answer on the web](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps101/Spring11/hw/hw2sol.pdf), given  involving subtracting a constant. I don't get why that's needed, I thought I had shown what was needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciate, starting Monday I'm enrolled in an algorithms class and I don't want to get behind!

We are using the CLRS book (surprise) and though I appreciate the amount of information in it, I'd rather have some more resources. I've really enjoyed a datastructures class and I really think I can enjoy this as well, but more resources would be very much appreciated.

Comment: We have a [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) with ample material about solving recurrences, in particular [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823/98).

Comment: Your substitution proves nothing. You use the claim to derive the claim -- that's not very helpful.

Comment: @Raphael This is proof by induction.

Comment: Your solution looks fine, though you'd better write it as an induction, i.e $T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 \leq c\lg(n/2) + 1$ and so on. You also need to take care of the base case, and notice that you get a condition on $c$ (not all $c$ work).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No, it's not. What is written there *could* be used as the inductive step, true. Given the level of the question, I would not assume that Oxymoron knows what happens there; the question even says "substitution method".

Comment: Another classical method for this proof is to consider $T'(k):=T(2^k)$ and show that it's $O(k)$, then revert to $T$.

Comment: All right, the master method will follow in the next part, but up until then im stuck with induction and subtitution.
I thought I had shown here that when I substitute the guess into the recurrence, it 'seems to work out'. But apparantly I'm still missing some stuff.I guess this has to do with establishing bounds. But how do I choose a lowest bound? For example if I would say T(0) I just get 1, since 0/2 = 0. Is this my base for the induction?

Answer (score 1):

Luckily i had 2 day ago the algorithm exam and so i was able to solve your question :-)
When solving recurrences try first to use the Master method, if you can't succeed than try other methods.

[image]

Comment: 1) The asker explicitly asks for how to do the "direct" proof. 2) Please type your solution; you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Answer (score 0):

**An easy way to solve recurrence relations**

Using your example:

T(n) = T(n/2)+1 is O(lgn)

T(1) = 0 .....suitable basecase

**STEP 1**

Solving the recurrence relation

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + 1

      = T(n/4) + 1 + 1

      = T(n/8) + 1 + 1 + 1
      :
      :
      = T(n/2^k) + k    ...(3)      (this step summarizes the recursive steps)
```

**STEP 2**

Now, let

```
      n/2^k = 1

      n = 2^k .... (1)

      also k = logn .... (2)
```

**STEP 3**

Substituting (1) and (2) in (3)

```
 T(n) = T(n/n) + logn

      = T(1) + logn

      = 0 + logn    (recall T(1) = 0)

      = logn
```

Hence: Order is O(logn)

note: logn is of base 2

Comment: Technically, you still need to prove the result correct; "..." is a good way to find a hypothesis, though.

Comment: you're right .. then you use Mathematical Induction to prove